# how to output a standings table on the fly from a mysql table of football [soccer] results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have been trying to find something about this topic and I can't seem to find anything, there were a few questions on here but they didn't work for my particular project.

I asked a similar question about updating the table but its not going to work for what I actually want
 here is the list of result.

```
 --------------------------------------------------------
|id  |   hometeam   |goalsfor|goalsagainst|   awayteam   |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |Inter Milan   |   3    |     1      | FC Barcelona |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |FC Barcelona  |   1    |     0      | Inter Milan  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 3  |Inter Milan   |   4    |     0      | AC Milan     |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 4  |AC Milan      |   0    |     2      | Inter Milan  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 5  |Real Madrid   |   2    |     0      | AC Milan     |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 6  |AC Milan      |   2    |     2      | Real Madrid  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 7  |FC Barcelona  |   2    |     2      | AC Milan     |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 8  |Real Madrid   |   2    |     0      | Inter Milan  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 9  |Inter Milan   |   3    |     1      | Real Madrid  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 10 |FC Barcelona  |   2    |     0      | Real Madrid  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 11 |Real Madrid   |   1    |     1      | FC Barcelona |
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically I want to be able to create a standings table ranking the teams in order, I want to present this table on the fly and not put it into the database

```
Pos Team           Pld  W   D   L   F   A   GD  Pts
1   FC Barcelona    5   2   3   0   8   5   3   9
2   Inter Milan     6   2   2   2   11  10  1   8
3   Real Madrid     6   2   2   2   8   8   0   8
4   AC Milan        5   0   3   2   8   12  -4  3
```

POS=Position W=won D=Draw L=Loss F=Goals scored For A=Goals scored against GD=Goals difference Pts=Points

I think the most efficient way to do this would be to assign wins, draws and losses, sum the goals scored and goals scored against and when echoing out the data - calculate the total number of games played and the points.

But how would I assign wins draws or losses? And calculate the goals scored and goals against?

Comment: Can you put column headings on the lower table so we know how each column should be calculated?

Comment: Do you have another table listing team names, or is the only way to get them all by selecting a distinct list of them from hometeam and awayteam?

Comment: @Wazzzy :D These are actual results from random games - only for example purposes, I am going to have lots of results - maybe 10-15 leagues for the last 60 - 70 years - maybe having them all in one mysql table might be a bad idea but I will think about it later. But I might add extra clauses selecting competitions according to what data the user wants.

Comment: @daiscog I will only have one table. However having a second table of team names might work better ...

Comment: I will suggest you one thing onto this...At some point of time I was also thinking of building this kind of web portal...But I was unable to find free feeds for the game...Thats why instead of going for this things first try to find feeds and if you get it from some where please please let me know....

Comment: @Wazzzy - what kind of feeds do you want and what are looking to do? I have a different idea but I maybe able to provide you some links - ask a question and I will answer :-) get some rep! :D

Comment: I am trying to create something like soccerway.com + adding a football league kind of feature to it... I will be needing free online feed for the game to get rid of live scores as in soccerway.com also with that i need db for previous matches and seasons... I will also be needing feeds like who are on bench also substitutes which country the player belongs who retiring ,negotiations and so on...I got to know some of the iframes code (like flashscore.com) for live feeds but that doesnt solve my problem. Thanks for replying...

Comment: that is very specific and not possible for free. I have similar ideas but my php isn't advanced enough yet but the thing I would do and suggest to you is php scrapping or trying to get the info through API.

I am taking an alternative manual route for the moment -  it will take longer but it is copyright free and legal and once the site is  up running I will pay for services like the ones you are suggesting.

I contacted Opta Stats that creates what you are looking for - I was quoted £135,000 a year for Serie A, La Liga, Bundesliga, Europa Cup and the Champions League! Might take a while!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First union the scores table together swapping the hometeam with the awayteam and swapping the goal counts. This gives you some source data that is easily aggregated and the query to generate the score card is something like this:

```
select 
    team, 
    count(*) played, 
    count(case when goalsfor > goalsagainst then 1 end) wins, 
    count(case when goalsagainst> goalsfor then 1 end) lost, 
    count(case when goalsfor = goalsagainst then 1 end) draws, 
    sum(goalsfor) goalsfor, 
    sum(goalsagainst) goalsagainst, 
    sum(goalsfor) - sum(goalsagainst) goal_diff,
    sum(
          case when goalsfor > goalsagainst then 3 else 0 end 
        + case when goalsfor = goalsagainst then 1 else 0 end
    ) score 
from (
    select hometeam team, goalsfor, goalsagainst from scores 
  union all
    select awayteam, goalsagainst, goalsfor from scores
) a 
group by team
order by score desc, goal_diff desc;
```

Comment: seems to be working as it isn't returning any errors - but just working out how to echo/print out the data - not slept enough so everything is a little hazy :S

Comment: This is genius, pure magic if you ask me! In my table I don't have team names, but I have foreign key id's referencing the id's on my teams table. Could you please tell me how I could join the team names on this table?

Comment: for SQL its great but if its PHP will be more general

Answer (score 4):

```
// connection stuff
$sql = 'select * from matchesTable';
$result = mysql_query($sql)

$standings = array ();
$standingTemplate = array ('matches' => 0, 'wins' => 0, 'draws' => 0, 'losses' => 0, 'goalsfor' => 0, 'goalsagainst' => 0, 'goalsdiff' => 0, 'points' => 0);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    handleMatch($row['hometeam'], $row['goalsfor'], $row['goalsagainst']);
    handleMatch($row['awayteam'], $row['goalsfor'], $row['goalsagainst']);

    print_r( usort(standings, 'comparePoints') );  // up to you to format the output as you like
}

function handleMatch($team, $goalsfor, $goalsagainst)
{
    global $standings, $standingTemplate;
    if ($goalsfor > $goalsagainst) 
    {
        $points = 3;
        $win = 1;
        $draw = 0;
        $loss = 0;
    }
    elsif ($goalsfor == $goalsagainst) 
    {
        $points = 1;
        $win = 0;
        $draw = 1;
        $loss = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        $points = 0
        $win = 0;
        $draw = 0;
        $loss = 1;
    }

    if ( empty($standings[$team]) )$standing = $standingTemplate;
    else $standing = $standings[$team];

    $standing['matches']++;
    $standing['wins'] += $win;
    $standing['draws'] += $draw;
    $standing['losses'] += $loss;
    $standing['goalsfor'] += $goalsfor;
    $standing['goalsagainst'] += $goalsagainst;
    $standing['goalsdiff'] += $goalsfor - $goalsagainst;
    $standing['points'] += $points;

    $standings[$team] = $standing;

}

function comparePoints($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['points'] == $b['points']) 
    {
        if ($a['goalsdiff'] == $b['goalsdiff']) return 0;
        return ($a['goalsdiff'] < $b['goalsdiff']) ? 1 : -1 ;
    }       
    return ($a['points'] < $b['points']) ? 1 : -1 ;
}
```

**NOTES**: I didn't test it and all, might be little bug (some `$` or `;` missing).

Comment: Some little bugs as you said, but easy to fix and the code is working.. cool.. thnx.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had to make quite more extended version of datatable. Although it is based on my own schema, but it maybe useful for someone (it is based on previous a'r answer):

```
  SELECT
    team_id                                             team_id,
    t.name                                              team_name,
    t.country                                           country,
    count(*)                                            matches,
    SUM(scored)                                         scored_total,
    SUM(conceided)                                      conceided_total,
    count(CASE WHEN scored > conceided
      THEN 1 END)                                       wins,
    count(CASE WHEN scored = conceided
      THEN 1 END)                                       draws,
    count(CASE WHEN scored < conceided
      THEN 1 END)                                       lost,
    sum(scored) - sum(conceided)                        balance,
    sum(
        CASE WHEN scored > conceided
          THEN 3
        ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN scored = conceided
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END)                                   points,
    count(CASE WHEN place = 'home'
      THEN 1 END)                                       home_matches,
    count(CASE WHEN place = 'home' AND scored > conceided
      THEN 1 END)                                       home_wins,
    count(CASE WHEN place = 'home' AND scored = conceided
      THEN 1 END)                                       home_draws,
    count(CASE WHEN place = 'home' AND scored < conceided
      THEN 1 END)                                       home_lost,
    SUM(CASE WHEN place = 'home'
      THEN scored
        ELSE 0 END)                                     home_scored,
    SUM(CASE WHEN place = 'home'
      THEN conceided
        ELSE 0 END)                                     home_conceided,
    count(CASE WHEN place = 'away'
      THEN 1 END)                                       away_matches,
    count(CASE WHEN place = 'away' AND scored > conceided
      THEN 1 END)                                       away_wins,
    count(CASE WHEN place = 'away' AND scored = conceided
      THEN 1 END)                                       away_draws,
    count(CASE WHEN place = 'away' AND scored < conceided
      THEN 1 END)                                       away_lost,
    SUM(CASE WHEN place = 'away'
      THEN scored
        ELSE 0 END)                                     away_scored,
    SUM(CASE WHEN place = 'away'
      THEN conceided
        ELSE 0 END)                                     away_conceided,
    GROUP_CONCAT((CASE
                  WHEN scored > conceided
                    THEN 'W'
                  WHEN scored = conceided
                    THEN 'D'
                  WHEN scored < conceided
                    THEN 'L'
                  END) ORDER BY date ASC separator '') streak
  FROM
    (
      (SELECT
         hm.date         date,
         hm.home_team_id team_id,
         hm.score_home   scored,
         hm.score_away   conceided,
         'home'          place
       FROM matches hm
       WHERE hm.season_id = :seasonId)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT
         am.date         date,
         am.away_team_id team_id,
         am.score_away   scored,
         am.score_home   conceided,
         'away'          place
       FROM matches am
       WHERE am.season_id = :seasonId)
    ) m
    JOIN teams t ON t.id = team_id
  GROUP BY team_id
  ORDER BY points DESC, balance DESC;
```