# how to set limit of game for table on the fly from mysql table for football results?

Tags: mysql

How to make limit for how many games to take from each club, I would like to have only ten games from each club.
This is the code for all games which I find here [how to output a standings table on the fly from a mysql table of football [soccer] results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009379/how-to-output-a-standings-table-on-the-fly-from-a-mysql-table-of-football-socce)

```
select 
team, 
count(*) played, 
count(case when goalsfor > goalsagainst then 1 end) wins, 
count(case when goalsagainst> goalsfor then 1 end) lost, 
count(case when goalsfor = goalsagainst then 1 end) draws, 
sum(goalsfor) goalsfor, 
sum(goalsagainst) goalsagainst, 
sum(goalsfor) - sum(goalsagainst) goal_diff,
sum(
      case when goalsfor > goalsagainst then 3 else 0 end 
    + case when goalsfor = goalsagainst then 1 else 0 end
) score 
from (
select hometeam team, goalsfor, goalsagainst from scores 
union all
select awayteam, goalsagainst, goalsfor from scores
) a 
group by team
order by score desc, goal_diff desc;
```

Comment: *Which* ten games would you like to take for each club?

Comment: last ten played, this query show all games from all clubs I would like to show only last 10 games from each club

Comment: How does one know when the games were played?

Comment: Every game has a date in database

Answer (score 0):

Use the LIMIT clause in your SELECT to return a limited number of rows.
Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: It will not work, limit on the end make how many club to show in the table.