# Sum of query generated columns

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT
the_team the_team,
te.name name,
count(CASE WHEN scored > conceded AND opponent = '306'
THEN 1 END) result_306,
count(CASE WHEN scored > conceded AND opponent = '2846'
THEN 1 END) result_2846,
```

Its a long query this is the important part.
full query [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51214744/2976631) if needed

I am trying to do something like this in the select

```
result_306 + result_2846 AS total_wins,
```

I am unable to select result_306 as its not defined 
I tried to do:

```
    @team1:= (count(CASE WHEN scored > conceded AND opponent = '2846'
  THEN 1 END))                                       team2846,
```

But this @team1 just returns Null
Is this not possible? or is there a way that I can sum these columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subquery:

```
SELECT the_team, name,result_306 + result_2846 AS total_wins
FROM (      
  SELECT the_team the_team,
     te.name name,
     count(CASE WHEN scored > conceded AND opponent = '306'
         THEN 1 END) result_306,
     count(CASE WHEN scored > conceded AND opponent = '2846'
        THEN 1 END) result_2846,
   FROM ...) sub
```

Comment: Am already using a complicated subquery to generate the results in the select, I posted a link to the query in the question. can I perform multiple sub query?

Comment: @Kash Yes, just wrap you  "complicated" subquery with outer outery.